# Unable to install scikit-bio in docker container

Tags: python, pip, pipenv, skbio

I was trying to install scikit-bio using `pipenv install scikit-bio` but I was facing some Cython issues, pasted the logs below. Can you please help me on how to resolve it.
I was using python 3.7 version in a docker container and using pip file and piplock files

```
Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
        else:
            matrix = self._convert_dict2d_to_matrix(substitution_matrix)
        # Set up our mask_length
        # Mask is recommended to be max(query_sequence/2, 15)
        if mask_auto:
            self.mask_length = len(query_sequence) / 2
                                                   ^
------------------------------------------------------------

skbio/alignment/_ssw_wrapper.pyx:584:51: Cannot assign type 'double' to 'int32_t'
```

Comment: I followed up on the skbio issue tracker here: https://github.com/biocore/scikit-bio/issues/1823